# C# HttpListenerResponse leaves temporary files

Tags: c#, httplistener

I wrote a Windows service using HttpListener. The service needs to send responses for every request which currently is done using HttpListenerResponse.

Unfortunately, a temporary file (with the response as content) is created and left behind under %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp for every response.

I'm basically using Microsofts example code from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistenerresponse(v=vs.110).aspx which shows the same behavior.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] pre = { "http://localhost:8080/" };
            SimpleListenerExample(pre);
        }

        // This example requires the System and System.Net namespaces.
        public static void SimpleListenerExample(string[] prefixes)
        {
            if (!HttpListener.IsSupported)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Windows XP SP2 or Server 2003 is required to use the HttpListener class.");
                return;
            }
            // URI prefixes are required,
            // for example "http://contoso.com:8080/index/".
            if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

            // Create a listener.
            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
            // Add the prefixes.
            foreach (string s in prefixes)
            {
                listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
            }
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
            // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            // Obtain a response object.
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            // Construct a response.
            string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
            // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            // You must close the output stream.
            output.Close();
            listener.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a long running Windows Service and believe these temporary files could be a problem after some time.

How can I send responses without temp. file creation?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the actual code, regardless on what's is based on.

Comment: You can't easily stop .net's webservices from creating those temp files. What you could do is have the service do a routine check, like every 24 hours, remove the temp files. You can start off by looking at Path.GetTempPath() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: Try dispose(or close) the response explicitly instead of closing the output -> response.Dispose();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, I figured it out. There's no problem with the code. The temp files were created by the tool *I'm Only Resting* (http://www.swensensoftware.com/im-only-resting) I used to send POST responses to test my service.

Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help.